# Ubuntu 20.04 LTS install stuck at Detecting file systems

Tags: system-installation

[installation stuck at Detecting file systems](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7eL39.jpg)

It seems to be stuck at Detecting file systems, and it also keeps saying "Source ID xxxxx was not found when attempting to remove it"
can anyone help?
I have downloaded the iso and used universal usb tool to put it on an external HDD, and now I'm trying to install it from this external HDD to a free space in my internal HDD.

Comment: From the information provided, this list shows what the problem may be: https://askubuntu.com/a/1190765/43926. A little more detail might help narrow this down. To start check ISO MD5SUM, try USB on another computer, try using Etcher or Rufus to install ISO.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue with 2204.

UPDATE: finally I resolved it. The reason is the installation USB disk is recognized in the partition phase. I selected one partition of USB disk as a mount point. So the installation tried to umount it for format but always failed.